# Control format of dataframes/tibbles displayed inline from Rmd chunk output

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

When I want to display a dataframe inline I never know which of the two formats it will appear as. For instance, mtcars often appears as:
[image]

Other times the dataframe will be formatted with up-down and left-right scrolling options.

[image]

Is there anyway to control this output style?

I've updated my RStudio version to 1.1.456 and tried paged.print=FALSE in the chunk options but cannot make the scroll view appear.

[image]

Comment: @DanY, I have updated the question with an example of the scrolling format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code chunk option **`paged.print`** controls this behavior.  You  can change it by writing the argument yourself, or you can click the gear icon for a code chunk and select/deselect the option there:

[image]

Comment: I tried this option, but it is not working, even after I updated my RStudio to newest version.

Comment: Set `paged.print=FALSE` to turn **off** the paging/scrolling.  Set `paged.print=TRUE` to turn in **on**.